# Making Linq navigation properties more obvious to developers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

It has been a common mistake in our code base that developers have written loops that unknowingly hit lazy loaded navigation properties in an Entity Framework object, thus firing off a DB call each iteration through the loop.  I am wondering if any Visual Studio extensions or clever tricks can be used to make it more obvious that a property in the automatically generated EF objects is in fact a navigation property, so that developers will more readily be aware to use caution.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- I prefer to keep domain objects minimal, with all properties being either columns or navigation properties. In addition to addressing the issue you describe, this makes it very obvious to consumers which properties can be used in LINQ queries (the one thing this won't help with is complex properties that aren't navigation properties)
- Close your unit of work as early as possible:

```
    // instead of
    using (var work = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var orders = work.Orders.Where(...).ToList();
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            // extra queries issued here
            Console.WriteLine(order.Customer.Name);
        }
    }
```

```
// consider
List<Order> orders;
using (var work = new MyDbContext())
{
    orders = work.Orders.Where(...).ToList();
}

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    // now this line throws an exception, so the developer
    // will go back and add the .Include() statement instead
    // of just silently creating slow code
    Console.WriteLine(order.Customer.Name);
}
```

- Consider turning off lazy loading. This can be done on a context level, or at the individual property level by just making properties non-virtual. While lazy-loading is convenient, it can be a performance trap and quite inconvenient for code reviewers as an extra thing to check
- Consider using a [DbInterceptor](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx) in your testing environment that looks for lazy-load queries (they are pretty distinctive) and logs the issue
- Get people in the practice of using SqlServer Profiler or [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) on while developing. This makes it easy to spot when too many queries are being issued.
- Using Roslyn, you could probably write an [analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which statically analyzes the code and displays some diagnostic when these properties are referenced to call them out.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. DbInterceptor looks like it might be a great way of catching these mistakes. The unit of work approach may be even better. I'll look into both.